# How can i import only discord from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js, bots

I've got an array of objects, these objects have an `identifiers` array with strings. One of these strings contains a Discord ID. The problem is its position is changing all the time, so I can't use the 4th identifier for example.

I only need the discord property.

[image]

I tried many things. I think it should be something like only "discord" property, but I have no idea how to solve that and code that up. Click on image to see more. There's json file there. It's all about `${players[i].identifiers[4]`

```js
const updateMessage = function() {
    getVars().then((vars) => {
      getPlayers().then((players) => {
        if (players.length !== LAST_COUNT) log(LOG_LEVELS.INFO,`${players.length} graczy`);
        let queue = vars['Queue'];
        let embed = UpdateEmbed()
        .addField('Status serwera','<:tak:847199217063297056> Online',true)
        .addField('W kolejce',queue === 'Enabled' || queue === undefined ? '0' : queue.split(':')[1].trim(),true)
        .addField('Graczy online',`${players.length}/${MAX_PLAYERS}\n\u200b\n`,true);
        // .addField('\u200b','\u200b\n\u200b\n',true);
        if (players.length > 0) {
          // method D
          const fieldCount = 3;
          const fields = new Array(fieldCount);
         fields.fill('');
          // for (var i=0;i<players.length;i++) {
          //   fields[i%4 >= 2 ? 1 : 0] += `${players[i].name}${i % 2 === 0 ? '\u200e' : '\n\u200f'}`;
          // }
          
          fields[0] = `**Mieszkańcy na wyspie:**\n`;
          for (var i=0;i<players.length;i++) {
            
            fields[(i+1)%fieldCount] += `${players[i].name} [${players[i].id}], ${players[i].identifiers[4]}`; 
          }
          for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
            let field = fields[i];
            if (field.length > 0) embed.addField('\u200b',`\n${fields[i]}`, true);
          }

        
        }
        sendOrUpdate(embed);
        LAST_COUNT = players.length;
      }).catch(offline);
    }).catch(offline);
    TICK_N++;
    if (TICK_N >= TICK_MAX) {
      TICK_N = 0;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<loop_callbacks.length;i++) {
      let callback = loop_callbacks.pop(0);
      callback();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the element from the `identifiers` array, but its position is not fixed, it can be anywhere.

Luckily, the element always start with the word 'discord', so you can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [`String#startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to find your discord ID. Check out the snippet below:

```js
let players = [{
  id: 1,
  identifiers: ["license:57349756783645", "xbl:85437852", "live:8953291341", "discord:89325813521519", "fivem:893123"],
  name: "foo",
  ping: 56
}, {
  id: 2,
  identifiers: ["xbl:57420987", "live:09123489", "discord:86543932136453", "license:865496782134", "fivem:584723"],
  name: "bar",
  ping: 41
}, {
  id: 3,
  identifiers: ["live:99532945", "discord:80521578413532", "license:60795634523", "xbl:1239435", "fivem:943921"],
  name: "bar",
  ping: 41
}]

players.forEach(player => {
  let discord = player.identifiers.find(i => i.startsWith('discord')).replace('discord:', '')
  console.log(`
  ID: ${player.id}
  Name: ${player.name}
  Discord: ${discord}
  `)
})
```

```js
// ...
fields[0] = `**Mieszkańcy na wyspie:**\n`;
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  const discord = players[i].identifiers.find((el) =>
    el.startsWith('discord'),
  ).replace('discord:', '');
  fields[
    (i + 1) % fieldCount
  ] += `${players[i].name} [${players[i].id}], ${discord}`;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, but i want only numbers, without this `discord:`. Anyway, thanks for your comment!

Comment: You can remove `discord:` from the string... I'll update my answer

Comment: could you help me again man?
i updated my code, but now it isn't working anymore. 
```js 
const discord = players[i].identifiers.find((el) =>
          el.startsWith('discord'),
          ).replace('discord:', '');
           let playerNames = Array.from(players.values()).map((c) =>

           `[${c.id}] ${c.name} - <@${discord}>`).join('\n');
           embed.addField('**Lista graczy:**\n',playerNames,false);

```
i stilll want to get discord id, but now it's showing discord id only for one member

Comment: I think it would be post a new question as it's kind of difficult to help this way.

Comment: @SzymonWilczek Please, don't edit and make significant changes to your question after getting a decent answer and marking it as accepted. Instead ask a new question featuring your new issue you have encountered. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to check it out, but it looks like you only define `discord` once, outside the `map` function.