# JSON file Array help discord.js

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

On start I would like to inform, that I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605827/how-can-i-import-only-discord-from-json-file) and it didn't help me, so please, help me, i tried everything.

I want discord property as well but on different code. My JSON file looks similar:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JiSN.png)

As I described, I want only discord property.
This is my code:

```js
let playerNames = Array.from(players.values())
  .map((c) => `[${c.id}] ${c.name} - <@${c.identifiers}>`)
  .join('\n');
embed.addField('**List:**\n', playerNames, false);
```

`c.identifiers` shows all identifiers from JSON file, I want only Discord, and only numbers which stands for Discord id of that user. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `players` an array? If it is, `Array.from(players.values())` is the same as `players`. Anyway, you can create a helper function to get the element. I already mentioned [how it works here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605912/6126373).

```js
let getDiscord = (player) =>
  player.identifiers
    .find((el) => el.startsWith('discord'))
    .replace('discord:', '');

let playerNames = Array.from(players.values())
  .map((c) => `[${c.id}] ${c.name} - <@${getDiscord(c)}>`)
  .join('\n');
embed.addField('**List:**\n', playerNames, false);
```

Comment: players are parameter from function, not an array, but i will try this code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array filter` (instead of map) and `c.identifiers.startsWith("Discord:")`

Comment: not working, sorry, but thanks for feedback. It has to be map, otherwise it's not showing players.